# When using form-search and input-append to create a search form, the search button show up short

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tk8Dc/) and code below:

```
<form class="form-search">
    <div class="input-append">
        <input type="text" id="search-query" class="search-query" />
        <input type="button" id="search-submit" value="Find" class="btn" />
    </div>
</form>
```

The button shows up fine in IE or Chrome, but when viewed with FF (ver 15 at least), the button show up a little short. 
Am I not using the Bootstrap correctly?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [doc](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms), you should use `button` where you are using `input`:

```
<form class="form-search">
    <div class="input-append">
        <input type="text" id="search-query" class="search-query" />
        <button type="button" id="search-submit" class="btn" >Find</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tk8Dc/7/

Comment: I'll steer away from evil inputs and use button for buttons.

Comment: I had to change `type=submit` to `type=button` to prevent the form being submitted.

Comment: @RayCheng you are right, in your question you were using `type="button"`. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add `height: auto;` on the input textarea

Another good trait (just another tip)to use on input is:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
-webkitbox-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
```